# R local database connection: Posit Cloud R Studio vs Local Laptop R Studio

Tags: r, odbc, dbi, r-dbi

I'm trying to use Posit Cloud to connect to a SQL Server database installed locally on my laptop.

The following, using only RStudio on my laptop,
runs/connects without issue:

```
# RStudio version: 2023.06.1 Build 524
# R version:  4.1.2

library(DBI)
library(odbc)

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
         Driver = "SQL Server",
         Server = "DESKTOP-4PC1LOK\\SQLEXPRESS", 
         Port = "1433", 
         UID = "publicaccess", 
         PWD = "password", 
         Database = "crime_camera_west_arlington", 
         timeout = 10)
```

However, when using RStudio in posit:Cloud to run the
same code as above I get:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1135: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found
```

What makes running this code in posit:Connect different?

Thanks.

Comment: Since R isn't running locally, I would assume you need to connect to the database by specifying the IP address.

Comment: It also looks like the SQL server driver is part of their professional driver plan. https://docs.posit.co/pro-drivers/ Are you using a paid service or their free service?

Comment: The `"SQL Server"` driver is _ancient_, it is no surprise (in fact, rather reassuring) that they don't offer that version in posit:cloud. Upgrade your driver to 17 at a minimum, current is 18; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16. (I'm amused to find https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/connect-history?view=sql-server-ver16 that includes the text *"The first "SQL Server" ODBC driver still ships as part of Windows Data Access Components. This driver isn't recommended for new development."*)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as mentioned by some of the responders, "SQL Server" is the incorrect driver. As suggested by ChatGPT, I ran odbc::odbcListDrivers(), in RStudio in Posit Cloud, to find the list of drivers available in Posit Cloud. "SQLServer" was listed for SQL Server. Substituting the correct driver removed the error message. Thanks for all responses.